# Set DegreeofParallelism when using AsOrdered c#

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I get the following error **"AsOrdered may only be called on the result of AsParallel, ParallelEnumerable.Range, or ParallelEnumerable.Repeat"**

When running the following code

```
myListofActions.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(threadCount)
                                        .AsOrdered().ForAll(x => DoMyTask(x));
```

this code works fine

```
myListofActions.AsParallel().AsOrdered().ForAll(x => DoMyTask(x));
```

Is there a way to set the WithDegreeOfParallelism in this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
myListofActions.AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Math.Min(threadCount, Environment.ProcessorCount))
        .ForAll(DoMyTask);
```

Comment: Not exactly, I just read the error message and re-ordered the calls accordingly. :)